# Get tagging counts by context using acts_as_taggable_on in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

In my Rails app I'm using `acts_as_taggable_on` and I have a fixed selection of tags that can be applied to both `Users` and `Posts` (the respective contexts are `:user_tags` and `:post_tags`.

Now what I'm trying to do is rank the tags in each context (Users and Posts) based on how many times they've been used in that context.

I tried this:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.where(:context => context).joins(:tag).select('DISTINCT tags.name').map{ |x| x.name}
```

But that simply returns the list of tags that have been used in a particular context at least once.

I can return and rank the most used tags pretty easily using this:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.most_used(5)
```

But that is combining counts from both contexts to create the ranking, which isn't accurate. There should be two separate rankings: most frequently applied to Users, and most frequently applied to Posts. If the tag "Developer" is attached to a certain Post, that tagging should only count towards "Developer" in the Post tag rankings and not the User tag rankings.

Comment: you found an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
a = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.where(context: :user_tags).includes(:tag).uniq(:tag_id).map{ |t| [ t.tag.name, User.tagged_with(t.tag.name).size] }.uniq
```

or

```
a = User.tag_counts_on(:user_tags).map{ |t| [ t.name, User.tagged_with(t.name).size] }.uniq
```

to build a nested array: `[ ["tag_name1", frequency], ["tag_name2", frequency] ]`

and then sort the array by frequency

```
a = a.sort_by{|a| -a[1]}
```

to get your ordered ranked list for Users.

The main drawback is the `User.tagged_with(t.tag.name).size` query which will be executed for each tag, which is not ideal for performance. Maybe there is a way to eager load it.